# remove specific class from html string using php

Tags: php, html

I have a string like

```
$string = '<img class="img-responsive animate scale animated" src="image/catalog/blocks/about-banner.jpg" alt="">';
```

I want to remove `img-responsive` class from it. How?

Comment: Use backspace. It should do the trick.

Comment: Use php search and replace inbuilt func tions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `$string = str_replace('img-responsive', '', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

In Php, You can use `str_replace`function as below:

```
$string = '<img class="img-responsive animate scale animated" src="image/catalog/blocks/about-banner.jpg" alt="">';
$new_string = str_replace('img-responsive', '' , $string);
```

Additionally, in Jquery, do like below:

```
$('.animate').removeClass('img-responsive');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all functions about replace on php : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

Hey u can just add below code in script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.animate').removeClass('img-responsive');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Question asked in PHP and html and you have answered on jquery which is not required.